# Choice list autocomplete

Tags: cognito-forms

If I have a long choice list and I'd like the user to be able to 'search' the choices. This is in part possible with the 'Allow Fill in' option, as it shows choices as you type. However, this allows the user to enter a value which is not in the choice list which is not desirable.

Can this be achieved?

Is there a custom error which can be used to validate the field has a choice from the choices in the list?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms. Yes, you can create a custom error to display when an entered choice is not in the list of choices. However, your calculation used to display the error would have to check the entered value against all allowed choices. Below is an example of a calculation to display an error when the choice is not one of the following: First Choice, Second Choice, or Third Choice.

[image]

Comment: OK - But if the list is long (which is why auto complete is needed) this required every value to be in the custom error - is there a way to check/query the choices already in the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a way to query against the list of choices.